# How to add an item to desktop right-click menu?

Tags: nautilus-actions

I'm trying to add an item to the nautilus context menu that would launch gnome-tweak-tool. Using Nautilus Actions Config Tool I've managed to add the item, however I want it to appear **only** when I right-click on the desktop, not in all folders. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the "Only show in" option, try and look for it: it is available through the command line tools of `nautilus-actions`.

I would like to elaborate more with the GUI interface but I just can't get the **Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool** to work. It won't open and exits with an error of `Trace/breakpoint trap`, but that bug does not belong here.

Comment: nautilus-actions was never upgraded properly in 11.10 for gtk3, it has been in 12.04 (3.1.4). So 11.10 users would need to build themselves or find a ppa. In 3.1.X the option in the gui is under the "Folders" tab